# Identify largest class in area

Tags: qgis, intersection, area, spatial-statistics

I have a layer of polygons with different land uses, and another layer of polygons with administrative areas. I'm trying to find a way to determine which land use is dominant (in terms of area) in each administrative area.

Land use polygons may cross administrative boundaries, and there may be more than one polygon of a particular land use in an administrative area.

In the example below administrative areas are shown by the thick black lines. In the left administrative area the dominant land use is "red", in the right administrative area the dominant land use is "blue".

[image]

How can I determine the dominant land use for each administrative area in QGIS?

I came up with a way of doing it using the intersection of the land use and administrative layers, running "Statistics by categories" on the intersection, and then using some convoluted 'aggregate' expressions on the original administrative layer to query the intersection, but I feel like there must be a more straightforward way of achieving this.

Comment: I think your way is good